# Azure DevOps Database backups w/ Git Repository

Tags: git, azure-devops

If we are using git for source control with an Azure DevOps server, what exactly is being backed up when you back up the database?  In other words, since Git is file-based, does the database for a project somehow contain the repository itself as well or just other project data only?

Answer (score 1):

On the server, there is one significant change to be aware of. Files aren’t stored on the file system like they would be when git is running on your local machine. Instead, they’re stored in the Azure DevOps Server SQL Server database. Apart from that, it's the same as any other git server out there.

If you will login to Azure DevOps Server SQL DB you will see `tbl_GitRepository` table.

[image]

More useful information you can find [here](https://www.richard-banks.org/2014/02/tfs-internals-how-does-tfs-store-git.html).